# Write a sql statement to query one table based on columns in other tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables: `pics`, `folders`, and `pics_by_folders`.

**pics**

```
 pic_ID | name | info
```

**folders**

```
folder_ID | name | info
```

**pics_by_folders**

```
folder_ID | pic_ID
```

I am trying to return all `pics` that meet requirements x,y,z but only if they are contained in folders meeting requirements j,k,l.  I hope I am explaining this in a way that makes sense.  My current statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM pics WHERE 
              pic_ID = 'x' AND 
              pics.name = 'y' AND 
              pics.info = 'Z'
JOIN pics_by_folder as pbf ON 
              pbf.pic_ID = pics.pic_ID
JOIN folders WHERE 
              folder_ID = 'j' AND 
              folders.name = 'k' AND 
              folders.info = 'l'
ON
              folders.folder_ID = pbf.folder_ID
```

This isn't working and I was thinking it had something to do with the ordering of statements or maybe sql doesn't allow `"JOIN x WHERE ..."` statements.  Either way, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you dont use any wildcard. `folders.name LIKE 'k' ` is the same as `folders.name = 'k'`

Comment: Yeah, I actually am using wildcards but didn't include them in the post, I'll edit it for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrong syntax!!!.**

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM pics 
JOIN pics_by_folder as pbf ON pbf.pic_ID = pics.pic_ID
JOIN folders ON folders.folder_ID = pbf.folder_ID
WHERE folder_ID = 'j' AND 
   folders.name LIKE 'k' AND 
   folders.info LIKE 'l' AND
   pic_ID LIKE 'x' AND 
   pics.name LIKE 'y' AND 
   pics.info LIKE 'Z'
```

**Some notes:**

Please always specify which columns you do want in your result set. Otherwise you will be confusing yourself because you don't know how many columns will there be in the result set.

`folders.name LIKE 'k'` is equivalent to `folders.name = 'k'`

if you want exact match then use `folders.name ='k'` otherwise use wild card operator `%` like below:
`folders.name LIKE '%k%'`

Comment: Yep that works great.  Thanks. I didn't realize all the JOINs went first and then all of the WHERE statements could be added at the end.  Also, I replaced the LIKEs in the post with =.  I am using the wild card operator in my code but didn't feel like it was important here.

Comment: No problem mate. But I would suggest you to go through the documentation on joins. Before jumping into writing more complex query using joins (or others) you definitely need it.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you want to do. But have you tried.

```
SELECT * FROM pics WHERE 
              pic_ID LIKE 'x' AND 
              pics.name LIKE 'y' AND 
              pics.info LIKE 'Z'
JOIN pics_by_folder as pbf ON 
              pbf.pic_ID = pics.pic_ID
JOIN folders on               folders.folder_ID = pbf.folder_ID and
              folder_ID = 'j' AND 
              folders.name LIKE 'k' AND 
              folders.info LIKE 'l'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that is the wrong sintaxis

Check the **[manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)**

```
SELECT
    [ALL | DISTINCT | DISTINCTROW ]
      [HIGH_PRIORITY]
      [STRAIGHT_JOIN]
      [SQL_SMALL_RESULT] [SQL_BIG_RESULT] [SQL_BUFFER_RESULT]
      [SQL_CACHE | SQL_NO_CACHE] [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS]
    select_expr [, select_expr ...]
    [FROM table_references]   --------------- THIS INCLUDE ALL JOIN
    [WHERE where_condition]   --------------- ALL RESTRICTION TOGETHER
    [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
    [HAVING where_condition]
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the statement like this

```
select * from pics where pic_id like 'x' and pics.name like 'y' and 
pics.info like 'z' and pic_id in 
(select pic_id from pics_by_folders where folder_id in 
(select folder_id from folders where folder_id ='j' and 
folders.name like 'k' and folders.info like 'l'))
```